# Track page view time using NodeJS behind CloudFlare

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cloudflare

I want to know how much time user is watching a specific page (Like Google Analytics).

I thought to open a xmlHttpRequest to my server and set timeout to about 30 minutes.
On the server, listen to request end, and log it on the server.

### Client Side

```
$(function($.get('/checktime')))  // start tracking on page load
```

### Server Side

```
app.use('/checktime',function(req){
    var start=new Date()
    req.on('end',log)
    req.on('disconnect',log)
    function log(){
        logToServer(new Date()-start) // Time the user spent on the page
    }
```

})

**The Questions:**

1. There is any other better way to track the time the user spent on the page?
2. There is any reason that the NodeJS server will end the connection, before the user leave the page?
3. The app is behind `cloudflare`. There is any timeout for cloudflare, so the connection will end before the user leave the page?
4. It is make any different to make the XMLHttpRequest using `get` or `post`?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementations I have seen lately open a WebSocket (fallback to long polling) and keep sending data ever few seconds to the server on the other end.  This also gives you the ability to gather more data using javascript and send that up to the logging server as well